# Basic queries related to client server communication

Tags: android-security, apache-synapse, matrix-synapse

I have some very basic queries on synapse and client communication. Thanks in advance.

1. I thought normal Android phones do not have secure storage with them (although some high end phones do have secure storage in the form of TEE). Right? So, how keys (if any) stored in android client are secured?
2. Where actually the keys are stored/located in matrix server and android/ios client. I could not get a confirmative answer on this.
3. How a normal android mobile phone is able to protect the key (without secure storage)? Does it use user's pattern or passphrase to protect it (which may provide weak entropy)?
4. Android Element can send data securely to Server using server side SSL, but how does the server sends data securely to Android client (without secure storage and hence without client side SSL)?